# Цикл движения блока на JS

Tags: html, css, javascript

Доброго времени суток знатоки) еще одна проблема у меня - так как я только постигаю JS а постигается лучше на практике от малого к великому столкнулся с еще одной затеей - кратко к делу есть функция такая

```
<script>
var posit = 200;

function movie() {  
    while() {   
        if (posit >= 400) {

        posit = 200;

        } else {

        posit += 1;

        }

    document.getElementById(1).style.left= posit+"px";

    setTimeout("",1000);
    }

}
</script>
```

Тобишь она каждую секунду двигает блок на 1 пиксель, (по замыслу) когда количество пикселей становится 400 - он обратно возвращается на 200 - но к сожалению цикл работает только 1 раз, думаю проблема в функции таймаута хммм
вот собственно сам блок ничего сложного

```
<div class="slide1" id="1"><img src="img/1.jpg" height="400"></div>
```

и его css

```
.slide1 {
position: absolute;
top: 200px;
left: 200px;
display: block;
}
```

и в конце так я запускаю функцию

```
<script>
movie();

</script>
```

Будьте снисходительны к моим скорее всего глупым вопросам) - я же только учусь все в таком положении были в свое время)

Comment: попробовал 2 взаимозапускающие функции

    function movie() {


 
 
 
  if (posit >= 400) {

  posit = 200;
 
  } else { 
 
  posit += 1;
 
  }
 
 document.getElementById(1).style.left= posit+"px";
 setTimeout(movie2(),2000);
 
 
    }

и

function
     movie2() {

 setTimeout(movie(),2000);
 
}

Comment: двигается как то рандомно и только при перезагрузке Оо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) **setTimeout** - устанавливает задержку перед однократным выполнением кода.
2) Вы не передаете в эту функцию ни **eval**-кода (внутри кавычек у вас пусто), ни имени функции, для которой надо вставить задержку.
3) Если вы хотите двигать блок каждую секунду, вам нужно либо корректное использование функции **setTimeout** внутри вашей функции **movie**, либо использование функции **setInterval** вне ее.

Пример с **setInterval**:

```
// Ищем наш блок
var block = document.getElementById(1);

/**
 * element - элемент, который будем двигать
 * from    - крайняя левая позиция
 * to      - крайняя правая позиция
 * step    - шаг в пикселях
 */

function move(element, from, to, step) {
    // Получаем текущую позицию блока из его inline-стилей
    var position = parseInt(element.style.left, 10);
    // В самый первый раз она будет не задана (inline-стилей нет)
    // В таком случае, устанавливаем начальную позицию в качестве текущей
    position = isNaN(position) ? from : position;
    if (position >= to) {
        position = from;
    } else {
        position += step;
    }
    element.style.left = position + "px";
}

// Буквально: "выполнять эту функцию каждую секунду"
setInterval(function () {
    move(block, 200, 400, 1);
}, 1000); // Двигаться будет ОЧЕНЬ медленно.
```

Пример с **setTimeout**:

```
var block = document.getElementById(1);

/**
 * element - элемент, который будем двигать
 * from    - крайняя левая позиция
 * to      - крайняя правая позиция
 * step    - шаг в пикселях
 * delay   - задержка перед смещением элемента
 */
function move(element, from, to, delay) {
    var position = parseInt(element.style.left, 10);
    if (position >= to) {
        position = from;
    } else {
        position += step;
    }
    element.style.left = position + "px";

    // Вставляем задержку перед рекурсивным вызовом функции
    // Буквально: "выполни эту функцию спустя время, указанной в переменной delay"
    // Поскольку у нас нужно передать вместе с функцией аргументы,
    // а setTimeout без eval-кода принимает на вход только имя функции,
    // используем анонимную функцию "обертку"
    setTimeout(function () {
        move(element, from, to, step, delay);
    }, delay);
}

// Первый раз функцию надо вызвать вручную
move(block, 200, 400, 1, 1000);
```

Ну и в конце **[ссылка на рабочий пример последнего варианта](http://jsfiddle.net/venzell/c264F/)**.

Comment: во
    <body>

    <script>
    var block = document.getElementById(1);
    function move(element, from, to, step) {

    var position = parseInt(element.style.left, 10);

    position = isNaN(position) ? from : position;
    if (position >= to) {
        position = from;
    } else {
        position += step;
    }
    element.style.left = position + "px";
    }
    setInterval(function () {
    move(block, 200, 400, 1);
    }, 1000); 
    </script>
    <div class="slide1" id="1"><img src="img/1.jpg" height="400"></div>
    <script>
 move(block, 200, 400, 1, 1000);
    </script>

</body>

Comment: всё равно 1 раз двигается только((